# How to set Dynamic height and width to a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have an HTML table with JSON Data, I am using data-tables to fix header and columns of my table, but while fixing these I have to set some width and height

What I am trying to do is

- How can I set dynamic width and height according to screen size
- I am using bootstrap for responsive design so I want whichever screen table opens it should take that screen size and render according to that
- While doing this

```
fixedColumns: {
    leftColumns: 2
}
```

the first 2 columns are appearing as scroll also which is bad user interface like [image: this] is there any browser dependency because on chrome it is rendering fine but on Mozilla, it is appearing like the image I have uploaded

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseInt(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}
var data = [{
    "amount": 135116,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "South Indian-1-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 133350,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "South Indian-2-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 89092,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 61661,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 80568,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18425,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 64091,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 16234,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 6233,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Takeaway",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18243,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },

  {
    "amount": 69946,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18197,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 8741,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Takeaway",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18820,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 78537,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 5060,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 49096,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58477,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 49933,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 9915,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 51209,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 2566,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 19602,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "North Indian",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 84490,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "South Indian-1-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 47952,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 56191,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 56829,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 4648,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 26051,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 14206,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 4322,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Takeaway",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 14271,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 82248,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 751,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  }
]

function formatData(data) {
  let toReturn = [];
  let dateWiseObj = {};
  let maxUniqueForOutlets = {};
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    if (!maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]]) {
      maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]] = [];
    }
    if (maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].indexOf(d["counter"]) == -1) {
      maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].push(d["counter"]);
    }

    if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]]) {
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]] = {};
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
    } else {
      if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]]) {
        dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
        dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
      } else {
        if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]]) {
          dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
        }
      }
    }

  });

  return {
    dateWiseObj: dateWiseObj,
    maxUniqueForOutlets: maxUniqueForOutlets
  };
};


function addTable(dataObj) {
  let dateWiseObj = dataObj.dateWiseObj;
  let maxUniqueForOutlets = dataObj.maxUniqueForOutlets;
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Outlet";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Totals";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(d) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = d; // ol names
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.colSpan = maxUniqueForOutlets[d].length + 1;
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Counter";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(k) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Total";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    maxUniqueForOutlets[k].forEach(function(d) {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = d; //counters name
      th.classList.add("text-center");
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    });
  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let completeTotal = 0;
  let outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal = {};
  Object.keys(dateWiseObj).forEach(function(k) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");

    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = k; //billdate

    row.appendChild(td);


    grandTotal = 0;
    outletWiseTotal = {};
    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function(d) {
      if (!outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d])
        outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] = {};
      outletWiseTotal[d] = 0;
      if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
        Object.keys(dateWiseObj[k][d]).forEach(function(i) {
          if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i]) {
            outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i] += parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
          } else {
            outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i] = parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
          }
          outletWiseTotal[d] += parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
        });
      }
      if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"])
        outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"] += outletWiseTotal[d];
      else
        outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"] = outletWiseTotal[d];
      grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[d];
    });
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right"); //grandTotal full column
    row.appendChild(td);

    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function(d) {
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[d].toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right"); //outlet total
      row.appendChild(td);
      if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
        maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = dateWiseObj[k][d][i] ? dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"].toLocaleString('en-IN') : "0";
          td.classList.add("text-right"); //all total
          row.appendChild(td);
        });
      } else {
        maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = "0";
          td.classList.add("text-right");
          row.appendChild(td);
        });
      }
    });
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    completeTotal += grandTotal;
    //console.log(outletWiseTotal);
  });

  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = completeTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  th.classList.add("text-right"); //complete total of all
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(d) {
    if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] && outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"]) {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"].toLocaleString('en-IN');
      th.classList.add("text-right");
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    } else {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = 0;
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    }
    maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
      if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] && outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i]) {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i].toLocaleString('en-IN');
        th.classList.add("text-right");
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
      } else {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = 0;
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
      }
    });
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  let divContainer = document.getElementById("tblOlcounterWise");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
  $(table).DataTable({ //adding datatabl functionality 
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 2
    }
  });
}

var dataObj = formatData(data);
addTable(dataObj);
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  /*how to make this dynamic*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/datatables.min.js"></script>

<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="tblOlcounterWise"></table>
</div>
```

my code is looking big but actually, it is not I have commented the line in my javascript code where data-tables functionality is added

**Edit**

whenever the no of rows increasing table is not properly scrolling vertically the fixed columns are fixed they are not scrolling vertically with all elements

```
[{"amount":49644,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"North Indian","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":194495,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"South Indian-1-Flr","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":80768,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Take-away counter 1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":60878,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":81999,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Trade Pos1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":8642,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Trade Pos 2","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":53822,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":15339,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":7548,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Takeaway","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":15432,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":107602,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":7711,"billdate":"2018-09-01","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":39,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"North Indian","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":118647,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"South Indian-1-Flr","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":119871,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"South Indian-2-Flr","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":109527,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Take-away counter 1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":64771,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":78037,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Trade Pos1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":20261,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Trade Pos 2","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":69946,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":18197,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":8741,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Takeaway","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":18820,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":78537,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":5060,"billdate":"2018-09-02","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":49096,"billdate":"2018-09-03","counter":"Take-away counter 1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":58477,"billdate":"2018-09-03","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":49933,"billdate":"2018-09-03","counter":"Trade Pos1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":9915,"billdate":"2018-09-03","counter":"Trade Pos 2","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":51209,"billdate":"2018-09-03","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":2566,"billdate":"2018-09-03","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":19602,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"North Indian","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":84490,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"South Indian-1-Flr","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":47952,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Take-away counter 1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":56191,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":56829,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Trade Pos1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":4648,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Trade Pos 2","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":26051,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":14206,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":4322,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Takeaway","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":14271,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":82248,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":751,"billdate":"2018-09-04","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":31224,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"North Indian","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":135675,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"South Indian-1-Flr","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":50704,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Take-away counter 1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":55118,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":49738,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Trade Pos1","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":13374,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Trade Pos 2","outlet":"JAYANAGAR"},{"amount":31923,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":14532,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Coffee Counter","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":2792,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Takeaway","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":16930,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"MALLESHWARAM"},{"amount":81019,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Restaurant","outlet":"KOLAR"},{"amount":4377,"billdate":"2018-09-05","counter":"Trade POS","outlet":"KOLAR"}]
```

Comment: Commenting the `$(table).DataTable({` code will remove the scroll from your inner table.

Comment: @randomSoul i didn't get you? i want to make my table scroll x and y axis whenever size of data increases  thats why i am using Data-tables

Comment: @viveksingh increase the width of the columns

Comment: that i know i can increase width of column, but when i am resizing my browser it is not fitting for new size, as u can check by running the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error Vivek was using Bootstrap for responsive.

Your second thinking that responsive is some kind of magic trick that a plugin such as FixedColumns will solve for any case.

Responsive is a design matter so it has to be solved before you even decide which technology are you going to use for your project. There should be a design of how your data table should look like in every device format.

However, I'm going to tell you how to fix the Firefox bug. You just have to add this code to you CSS:

```
.DTFC_LeftBodyLiner {
  overflow-y: initial!important;
  width: auto!important;
}
```

**UPDATE:** After our conversation on the chat I understood your other issue with the scroll. The solution was a combination of removing bootstrap responsive table:

```
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
```

and modifying the width of `div.dataTables_wrapper` to 100% and adding this little css:

```
.table.DTFC_Cloned {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

also changing #tblOlcounterWise `<table>` tag by a `<div>` tag, as there was a syntax error when embedding `<div>` tags directly inside the `<table>`.

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseInt(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}
var data = [{
    "amount": 135116,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "South Indian-1-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 133350,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "South Indian-2-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 89092,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 61661,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 80568,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18425,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 64091,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 16234,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 6233,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Takeaway",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18243,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },

  {
    "amount": 69946,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18197,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 8741,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Takeaway",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 18820,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 78537,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 5060,
    "billdate": "2018-09-02",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 49096,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58477,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 49933,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 9915,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 51209,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 2566,
    "billdate": "2018-09-03",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 19602,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "North Indian",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 84490,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "South Indian-1-Flr",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 47952,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Take-away counter 1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 56191,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 56829,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Trade Pos1",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 4648,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Trade Pos 2",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 26051,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 14206,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Coffee Counter",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 4322,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Takeaway",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 14271,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 82248,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Restaurant",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 751,
    "billdate": "2018-09-04",
    "counter": "Trade POS",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  }
]

function formatData(data) {
  let toReturn = [];
  let dateWiseObj = {};
  let maxUniqueForOutlets = {};
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    if (!maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]]) {
      maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]] = [];
    }
    if (maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].indexOf(d["counter"]) == -1) {
      maxUniqueForOutlets[d["outlet"]].push(d["counter"]);
    }

    if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]]) {
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]] = {};
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
      dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
    } else {
      if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]]) {
        dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]] = {};
        dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
      } else {
        if (!dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]]) {
          dateWiseObj[d["billdate"]][d["outlet"]][d["counter"]] = d;
        }
      }
    }

  });

  return {
    dateWiseObj: dateWiseObj,
    maxUniqueForOutlets: maxUniqueForOutlets
  };
};


function addTable(dataObj) {
  let dateWiseObj = dataObj.dateWiseObj;
  let maxUniqueForOutlets = dataObj.maxUniqueForOutlets;
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Outlet";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Totals";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(d) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = d; // ol names
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.colSpan = maxUniqueForOutlets[d].length + 1;
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Counter";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(k) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Total";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    maxUniqueForOutlets[k].forEach(function(d) {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = d; //counters name
      th.classList.add("text-center");
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    });
  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let completeTotal = 0;
  let outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal = {};
  Object.keys(dateWiseObj).forEach(function(k) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");

    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = k; //billdate

    row.appendChild(td);


    grandTotal = 0;
    outletWiseTotal = {};
    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function(d) {
      if (!outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d])
        outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] = {};
      outletWiseTotal[d] = 0;
      if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
        Object.keys(dateWiseObj[k][d]).forEach(function(i) {
          if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i]) {
            outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i] += parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
          } else {
            outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i] = parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
          }
          outletWiseTotal[d] += parseInt(dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"] || "0");
        });
      }
      if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"])
        outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"] += outletWiseTotal[d];
      else
        outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"] = outletWiseTotal[d];
      grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[d];
    });
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right"); //grandTotal full column
    row.appendChild(td);

    Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).map(function(d) {
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[d].toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right"); //outlet total
      row.appendChild(td);
      if (dateWiseObj[k][d]) {
        maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = dateWiseObj[k][d][i] ? dateWiseObj[k][d][i]["amount"].toLocaleString('en-IN') : "0";
          td.classList.add("text-right"); //all total
          row.appendChild(td);
        });
      } else {
        maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
          td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = "0";
          td.classList.add("text-right");
          row.appendChild(td);
        });
      }
    });
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    completeTotal += grandTotal;
    //console.log(outletWiseTotal);
  });

  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = completeTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  th.classList.add("text-right"); //complete total of all
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(d) {
    if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] && outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"]) {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d]["total"].toLocaleString('en-IN');
      th.classList.add("text-right");
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    } else {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = 0;
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    }
    maxUniqueForOutlets[d].forEach(function(i) {
      if (outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d] && outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i]) {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = outletandCounterWiseCompleteTotal[d][i].toLocaleString('en-IN');
        th.classList.add("text-right");
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
      } else {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = 0;
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
      }
    });
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  let divContainer = document.getElementById("tblOlcounterWise");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
  var $winHeight = $(document).height();
  var $bodyHeight = $winHeight - 90;
  $(table).DataTable({ //adding datatabl functionality 
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": $bodyHeight + "px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 2
    }
  });
}

var dataObj = formatData(data);
addTable(dataObj);
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /*how to make this dynamic*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color: black;
}
.DTFC_LeftBodyLiner {
  overflow-y: initial!important;
  width: auto!important;
}
.table.DTFC_Cloned {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/datatables.min.js"></script>

<!--div align="center" class="table table-responsive"-->
  <div id="tblOlcounterWise"></div>
<!--/div-->
```

Comment: 1st thing is Here i am talking about ` .dataTables_wrapper {
  width:1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
} ` the width i am giving i static just want to know with j query or java-script can i make it dynamic, secondly the Firefox (Mozilla) issue  is still not resolved

Comment: Check again please, I forgot to put the !important ;)

Comment: Now vertical as well as Horizontal scroll both are coming for 1st two columns

Comment: yup its working fine now but my main issue is still not resolved

Comment: Man, one thing at a time, haha For the other issue you are going to have to explain a bit more what you want to do... what you want is that the element `.table-responsive` takes 100% of the parent? Because I don't understand why you want to use dynamic width and height instead of CSS

Comment: My main question was that only yup like that almost, as currently i am giving width manually which is causing issue when i am rendering table on different (size) device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192435/discussion-between-daniel-abril-and-vivek-singh).

Comment: I'd upvote this for your words about "responsive" not being any kind of magic, but then I'd downvote for your use of "my dear Vivek", as that's rather patronizing.

Comment: Hi @Heretic, ok as you will. I'm Spanish, I was just trying to smooth a bit my critic words regarding the use of Bootstrap for this purpose. In fact I've been talking with Vivak on the chat to understand better the issue and I've just updated my answer with the solution to his problem which was basically removing the bootstrap `.table-responsive` element.

Comment: @DanielAbril sir one small doubt how can i make  ` "scrollY": "200px",` dynamic height as for all devices

Comment: @viveksingh  try it now. Should be working. That parameter creates a max-height inline, now is taking the windows height less 90px, which is the sume of the 3 headers rows

Comment: @DanielAbril sir i am facing too many issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898721/html-table-misaligned-rows-in-fixed-columns/55899449#55899449 please check this once

Comment: @viveksingh, try explaining better the case of that issue in your question. What you've done when that happened? In which platform... everything that can help us help you. If you're not sure, go back to the point where it was working and start again checking step by step