# Why isn't fixed column working using Data-table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am working on Data-tables I have a JSON data from which I am creating an HTML table.

I have some requirements for that I am using data-tables what my issue is I am using data-table fixed-columns to fix my column but the table is not rendering correctly it is showing up like:

[image: this]

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseInt(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}

var data = [{
    "amount": 137551,
    "billdate": "2018-12-01",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 130832,
    "billdate": "2018-12-02",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 84501,
    "billdate": "2018-12-03",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 81938,
    "billdate": "2018-12-04",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104634,
    "billdate": "2018-12-05",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 95217,
    "billdate": "2018-12-06",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 114856,
    "billdate": "2018-12-07",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104277,
    "billdate": "2018-12-08",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104180,
    "billdate": "2018-12-09",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 76160,
    "billdate": "2018-12-10",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 94503,
    "billdate": "2018-12-11",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 87724,
    "billdate": "2018-12-12",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 146463,
    "billdate": "2018-12-13",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 150194,
    "billdate": "2018-12-14",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100765,
    "billdate": "2018-12-15",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 96188,
    "billdate": "2018-12-16",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 94390,
    "billdate": "2018-12-17",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 105079,
    "billdate": "2018-12-18",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 133846,
    "billdate": "2018-12-19",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 151600,
    "billdate": "2018-12-20",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 190293,
    "billdate": "2018-12-21",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100150,
    "billdate": "2018-12-22",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 68592,
    "billdate": "2018-12-23",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 128454,
    "billdate": "2018-12-24",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 138538,
    "billdate": "2018-12-25",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 78394,
    "billdate": "2018-12-26",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 82636,
    "billdate": "2018-12-27",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 70039,
    "billdate": "2018-12-28",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 62300,
    "billdate": "2018-12-29",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  }
]

let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("tblOlSalesSummary");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Totals";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-in');

    th.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-in');
  th.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);
    let total = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          el = d.amount;
        }
      });
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-in');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
  $(table).DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "200px",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 2,
    }
  }).columns.adjust().draw();
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.DTFC_LeftBodyLiner {
  overflow-x: hidden
}

.table.DTFC_Cloned {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
<div id="tblOlSalesSummary" class="table table-responsive"></div>
```

As per guided by DeclanMcD to remove the the CSS CDN of data-table to get the desire look I am looking for, but I don't think removing CSS CDN od data-table is good idea. As you all can check [image: here] I am fixing 3 columns of my table their alignment is not perfect which will be not good user experience

When I am adding data-table CSS cdn to my code then it is coming like above before edit. I don't know how to fix this one as it is creating lots of issue for me

Can I achieve that using pure CSS I have Googled a lot and found some solutions but when mixing them with my CSS they are not working

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues in your HTML. You have missed loading the stylesheet required by the FixedColumns extension. And you have loaded the default datatable's stylesheet which will not work correctly with bootstrap 4's styles.

To fix this issue :-

1. Go to the [datatables CDN](https://cdn.datatables.net/) page.
2. Find a section named **Styling options** and click on **Bootstrap 4** button.
3. Replace your referenced datatables CSS with the bootstrap 4 one available in **DataTables** section.
4. Add another CSS file to your HTML which is present inside **Extensions -> FixedColumns** section.

You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ParaBolt/f20roshe/44/) where your code is now working as intended after applying the fixes.

After loading the correct stylesheets, the following CSS will also become unnecessary :-

`.DTFC_LeftBodyLiner {
  overflow-x:hidden 
}`

An overflow scrollbar was appearing on the fixed columns only because incorrect CSS was loaded in the first place, which might have prompted you to add those styles to hide the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

I have copied your code into a fiddle

[View the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/m19gfapk/)

You haven't said what it is supposed to look like but I've removed the css file

```
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
-->
```

and it appears to be displaying as intended?

update: I have added the following style to fix the extra spaces that was appearing. It has also fixed the column scrolling issue.:

```
.table {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Check out the fiddle now.

Comment: hey yup its rendering correctly but some look and feel is appearing badly like space between tbody and thead and while scrolling tbody  `CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD` this column is scrolling bit more

Comment: hey sir i am not accepting your answer because it is not a  good practice to not to use datatable css cdn, as it is causing me some issues in my table ui when i am using it with other tables

Answer (score 0):

I added the below css to your code. widths should not be in pixels for datatable divisions.

```
#DataTables_Table_0, .DataTables_scrollHeadInnner, .dataTable {width:100% !important;}
```

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseInt(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}

var data = [{
    "amount": 137551,
    "billdate": "2018-12-01",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 130832,
    "billdate": "2018-12-02",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 84501,
    "billdate": "2018-12-03",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 81938,
    "billdate": "2018-12-04",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104634,
    "billdate": "2018-12-05",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 95217,
    "billdate": "2018-12-06",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 114856,
    "billdate": "2018-12-07",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104277,
    "billdate": "2018-12-08",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104180,
    "billdate": "2018-12-09",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 76160,
    "billdate": "2018-12-10",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 94503,
    "billdate": "2018-12-11",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 87724,
    "billdate": "2018-12-12",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 146463,
    "billdate": "2018-12-13",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 150194,
    "billdate": "2018-12-14",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100765,
    "billdate": "2018-12-15",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 96188,
    "billdate": "2018-12-16",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 94390,
    "billdate": "2018-12-17",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 105079,
    "billdate": "2018-12-18",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 133846,
    "billdate": "2018-12-19",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 151600,
    "billdate": "2018-12-20",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 190293,
    "billdate": "2018-12-21",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 100150,
    "billdate": "2018-12-22",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 68592,
    "billdate": "2018-12-23",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 128454,
    "billdate": "2018-12-24",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 138538,
    "billdate": "2018-12-25",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 78394,
    "billdate": "2018-12-26",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 82636,
    "billdate": "2018-12-27",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 70039,
    "billdate": "2018-12-28",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  },
  {
    "amount": 62300,
    "billdate": "2018-12-29",
    "outlet": "CHEF BAKERS BROOKFIELD"
  }
]

let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("tblOlSalesSummary");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Totals";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-in');

    th.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-in');
  th.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);
    let total = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          el = d.amount;
        }
      });
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-in');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
  $(table).DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "200px",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 2,
    }
  }).columns.adjust().draw();
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.DTFC_LeftBodyLiner {
  overflow-x:hidden 
}
.table.DTFC_Cloned {
background-color: #fff;
}
table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
 border: 1px solid white;
 white-space: nowrap;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 9pt;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 
}


table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
 border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
 white-space: nowrap;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 8pt;
 background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: black;
   
}

#DataTables_Table_0, .dataTables_scrollHeadInner, .dataTable  {
  width:100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/fc-3.2.5/fh-3.1.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
<div id="tblOlSalesSummary" class="table table-responsive"></div>
```

Comment: Same issue, columns are breaking ,not matching up with headers

Comment: your concern on chef bakers brookfield column??

Comment: look when i am removing link tag of data-table css then `chef bakers brookfield `column is alingining correctly but headers are not matching with table tbody, while using your approach of `100%` datatable is aligning on full screen but when i am resizing the page it is not aligning correctly please check once with code

Comment: Hey if you can help please help, as using your code when outlets increases from 1 to many as here it is only one `chef bakers brookfield` but when it is more than one scroll is causing misalignment of columns with headers  and also using 100% width is not a ideal solution if i have data which can fit in small size of the page than there is no need to show it on full page

Answer (score 0):

Add both datatables fixed columns CSS and JS files as reference, its required:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.1/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.1/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
```

Add the below CSS code:

```
<style>
.DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper {
    color: black !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}

.DTFC_LeftBodyLiner {
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

jQuery datatable code as below:

```
$("#YourTable").DataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "order": [],
        "fixedHeader": true,
         paging: true,
        "scrollY": 400,
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "fixedColumns": {
            leftColumns: 3 //Your column number here
        },
 });
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Add this cdn link in your script,

https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/4.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js

Add this code in your data table js code file,

```
scrollX: true,
fixedColumns:   {
  leftColumns: 1,
  rightColumns: 1,
},
```